# JavaScript Cannot access variable in multiple value return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My application is crashing because of the second part of this render statement `c is not defined` (after the comma in return).

I want to render not only this element as the `CategoryTreeFork` component, but also render it's children along-side it as the same component.

Am I making a mistake in trying to access that variable?

```
<div className="categories-narabikae">
    <p>Displayed Categories </p>
    {   
        filterActiveCategories(categories).map((c, idx) =>  
            <CategoryTreeFork 
                key={idx}
                parentCat={null}
                thisCat={c}
                level={1}
                dropEvent={this.handleDropEvent}
            />

            ,   

            c.children 
                ? c.children.map( (c2, idx) =>
                <CategoryTreeFork
                    key={idx}
                    parentCat={c}
                    thisCat={c2}
                    level={2}
                    dropEvent={this.handleDropEvent}
                />
            )   
            : null
        )   
    }   
</div>
```

*Edit:* it looks like during the first render of the page the array that I am mapping is empty (has not yet retrieved categories from API) -- would this possible trigger the error?

Comment: You cannot return multiple values from a function in JS. From the code you've provided, it looks like you're trying to do recursive rendering. I'd suggest the `CategoryFork` be called recursively, each time passing new children as prop.

Comment: Does it really not? I thought you could do `return (val1, val2)` in ES6. I have to avoid recursive components on this one so I think I will have to prepare the data in my array with additional attributes to get the desired effect with sibling components.

Comment: `I thought you could do return (val1, val2) in ES6` You can, but not in this way with React. See the comma operator. (discards all but the last item)

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh wow that's really useful, I never realized that's how it was being used. Well, pretty much answers my question if you wanna submit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it looks like during the first render of the page the array that I am mapping is empty (has not yet retrieved categories from API) -- would this possible trigger the error?

You're (accidentally) using the comma operator:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

So, the first `CategoryTreeFork` will be ignored by the interpreter; only the last value in a comma-separated list will actually be used.